# Distinct values obtained by 1's and 2's with + and *

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Is there a way to calculate the number of distinct values that can be obtained by using at most A 1's and B 2's with the operations + and *? Multiplication takes precedence and bracketing is not allowed.

For example, say that A=2 and B=2. Then

```
1: 1 and 1*1
2: 1*2 and 1*1*2 and 2 and 1+1
3: 1+2 and 1*2 + 1
4: 1+1+2 and 2+2 and 2*2 and 1*2*2 and 1*1*2*2 and so on
5: 2*2 + 1 and 2+2+1 and 2+2+1*1
6: 1+1+2+2 and 2*2 +1+1
```

So the values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) can be obtained using 2 1's and 2 2's. But 8 cannot be formed because bracketing values is not allowed. Hence the answer is 6 (number of distinct values obtainable).

I have observed that,

```
If B = 0, then the answer is A.
If A = 0, then the answer is (number of possible values for B).
* for A values have no effect. So only + should be considered for A.
```

From there, I'm kind of stuck. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `(1+1)*2*2 = 8`?

Comment: @Carsten Sorry, forgot to mention that bracketing values is not allowed. Edited my question

Comment: This is not a Math question?

Comment: @Avempace That, I'm also not sure... I posted it here 'cos I'm looking for an algorithm.

Comment: I would think that it will be a fibonacci or similar. You have a solution and you will keep extending it by adding one more 1 or 2. So the solution will be the previous one plus some more cases.

Comment: @Avempace Hmmm, didn't think of it that way. And it does sound good. If you can add some more to it and post as an answer, I'll accept it. Oh, but one more thing. A can be large (10^9) and B is relatively small (10^3). So, will that be an issue?

Comment: I am not sure, I think is good A is large. The biggest number that you will have is 2^B + A. You will have every number between 2^B and the MAX. But what about smaller numbers? (2^B) - 1 ?? You will need A big enough that (2^(B-1)) + A = (2^B) - 1. But when B is big this will be hard because exponential growth. What I am trying to think is if we will have empty spaces for numbers lower than the MAX number you can reach. I will not have time now to think about it any more... I leave the fun for someone else!